# Comparing multiple numerical values in Perl

Tags: perl

Say I have a few variables, `$x, $y, $z, $a, $b, $c`, and I want to make sure they all have the same value.

Can I test with something like `if ($x == $y == $z == $a == $b == $c)` to avoid multiple binary comparisons, i.e. (`if $x == $y and $x == $z and $y == $z ...`)?

Is there any way I can do all the comparing with one short and simple test?

Comment: I think so. Give it a try!

Comment: Too many binary comparisons if you have 4 or more variables. :))) Too many for me, at least.

Comment: Tried it out. Multiple comparison doesn't work. Does anybody know any tricks?

Comment: @Stefan: If you need to ascertain identity of all variables, it is N-1 comparisons. And no, you can't do `$x == $y == $z`, that will compare `$z` with true or false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if ( grep $x != $_, $y, $z, $a, $b, $c ) {
    print "not all the same\n";
}
```

Comment: You just beat me to this solution :)

Answer (score 4):

`$x == $y and $x == $z and $y == $z` is equivalent to `$x == $y and $x == $z` due to equality being transitive. This latter one is also the optimal solution, with N-1 comparisons for N variables.

If you have an array, you can use `uniq` from `List::MoreUtils`:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);

my @arr1 = qw(foo foo foo foo foo foo);
my @arr2 = qw(foo BAR foo foo foo foo);

print "arr1: ", (uniq @arr1) == 1 ? "All same" : "Different" , "\n";
print "arr2: ", (uniq @arr2) == 1 ? "All same" : "Different" , "\n";
```

(If you have more than several variables and don't have an array, it might be worth considering to rewrite the code...)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [List::MoreUtils::first_index](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils#first_index-BLOCK-LIST).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::MoreUtils qw( first_index );

my ($x, $y, $z, $a, $b, $c) = (1) x 6;

if (are_all_same($x, $y, $z, $a, $b, $c)) {
    print "They all have the same value\n";
}

$c = 3;

unless (are_all_same($x, $y, $z, $a, $b, $c)) {
    print "At least one has a different value than the others\n";
}

sub are_all_same {
    my $x = shift;
    -1 == first_index { $x != $_ } @_;
}
```

Of course, there is the issue of whether having so many variables in a small scope is appropriate (are you suffering from Fortranitis?), and whether one should use a hash to avoid a problem like this in the first place.

You can also use `are_all_same` with a large array, and it will impose minimal additional space and time penalties.

Comment: Wow, fantastic answers and comments. Thanks Sinan Unur, Amadan, and ysth. ysth gets bonus points for the conciseness of his answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

If they are all the same, then in particular the first must be equal to all the remaining ones. So that suggests the use of `List::Util::all`:

```
use List::Util 'all';

if( all { $x == $_ } $y, $z, $a, $b, $c ) {
  ...
}
```